# Any tool to parallelize bash commands with different CPU requirements?

Tags: bash, parallel-processing

I'm looking for a tool that enables me to parallelize, up to a number of cores, a list of bash commands, each with different CPU requirements.

For example, if I have a machine with 3 cores, and I have the following  list of jobs:

1. run x (uses 1 cores)
2. run y (uses 2 cores)
3. run z (uses 3 cores)

I'd like the tool to run the commands in parallel but respecting the fact I only have 3 cores, so the workload would look something like

```
(empty),              (empty), (empty)
Job 1 (using 1 core), (empty), (empty)
Job 1 (using 1 core), Job 2 (using 2 cores)
Job 1 done,           Job 2 (using 2 cores)
(empty),              Job 2 (using 2 cores)
(empty),              Job 2 done
Job 3 (using 3 cores)
```

Comment: Are you trying to parallelize/manage execution for the shell commands themselves (which will run locally), or for the docker containers that they generate (which will run on a docker host that may not be local)?

In general, docker run is not CPU intensive in and of itself

Comment: I removed the docker specifics, as they're not that important. My jobs are designed to take multiple cores.

Comment: You could probably write a smallish Perl, or Python, or PHP, script using semaphores that can be called to either get or release N counts of a semaphore and wrap your jobs between a `get N` and `release N` call... https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=299565

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My sense is to split this answer into two. a) Shell b) Docker and provide a preamble.

nb. The original question pertained to running parallel docker containers. The question remit was then broadened to the topic of parallel shell scripts.

### Preamble / Caveat

Parallel programming in an ideal situation delivers a factor of N speedup when running on a parallel computer that has N processing elements. If you read up on [Amdahl’s law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law) you'll note this is not always true due to the effort required to parallelize the task. Any interdependencies between the parallel tasks will quickly create complexity and likely negate the effort to paralelise the operations.

### Shell Scripting

If you truly wish to create a set of parallel jobs via a shell my personal recommendation is to use [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/). It provides extremely fine-grained control of both CPU and thread attributes.

It also comes with a lot of detailed [code example](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-Working-as-xargs--n1.-Argument-appending)s.

#### Template Example:

Let us assume a website stores images like:

```
http://www.example.com/path/to/YYYYMMDD_##.jpg
```

where YYYYMMDD is the date and ## is the number 01-24. This will download images for the past 30 days:

```
  getit() {
    date=$(date -d "today -$1 days" +%Y%m%d)
    num=$2
    echo wget http://www.example.com/path/to/${date}_${num}.jpg
  }
  export -f getit

  parallel getit ::: $(seq 30) ::: $(seq -w 24)
```

***Question:*** 
"*What is the issue with the above parallel task approach?*"

***Answer:*** Well, the parallelism of the task is looking great, however, the performance is now bounded by the IO bandwidth to the website... Thus, too many parallel tasks may cause slower overall task completion.

### Docker

On the docker run command, you can define can constrain CPU resources using

`--cpu=n`

https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#configure-the-default-cfs-scheduler

the example below simply launches a set of (presumed) non-dependent docker containers via a shell `for` loop construct. This is a typical approach to run a set of non-dependent containers in a parallel fashion. Note: The programs start in series but run independently, any interdependence could be built into the docker IO communication backplane (i.e. They might communicate via the TCP) though frankly at that point you are getting into a very technical discussion on what you are actually trying to do with parallelism. (Beware, Dragons...)

#### Example Template

```
  1 #!/bin/bash
  2
  3 n="$1"
  4 if [[ "$n" == "" ]]; then
  5     echo "You did not specify number of parallel runs to launch. Defaulting to 10."
  6     n="10"
  7 fi
  8
  9 mkdir $PWD/openjdks
 10
 11 for i in $(seq 1 $n); do
 12         mkdir $PWD/openjdks/$i
 13         docker run -d\
 14            --name=<name>$i \
 15            --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN \
 16            --cpu=<number of CPU required> \
 17            -v $PWD/openjdks/$i:/tmp \
 18            -e DISTRO=centos \
 19            -r mirror \
 20            -filename java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.41-1.13.13.1.el7_3.x86_64.rpm \
 21            -path /tmp/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.41-1.13.13.1.el7_3.x86_64.rpm \
 22            -log /tmp/mylog.log
 23 done
```

I hope the above points you in the right direction.

Comment: Sorry; I guess the docker comment was misleading. Does this command run in parallel? I've updated the question above.

Comment: @richliaw Look at line 11 in the template, it launches n containers. Line 5 is a hint.

Comment: @richliaw I think the stuff about GNU Parallel under "Shell Scripting" is what you're looking for. The docs indicate that you can give it a list of jobs, and tell it not to start the next job if the CPU load is over a certain threshold.